# Show mean value by hour of day using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas df that contains the following two columns, one called 'likes' which contains the number of likes a tweet received and another called 'hour' which shows the hour of day during which the tweet was made (01-24).

How can I plot a bar chart that shows mean likes grouped by hour of day.

I tried `plt.bar(df['hour'],df['likes'].mean())` but it is not working.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
mean_likes = df[['hour','likes']].groupby('hour',as_index=False).mean()

graph = sns.barplot(x='hour',y='likes',data=mean_likes, color='royalblue')

plt.show
```